# how to work with Sql table named Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table named Group in my database , when I try to work on it it gave error :

```
 SELECT GroupID,GroupName FROM Group
```

it said :

```
     Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
     Incorrect syntax near 'Group'.
```

I know that Group is illegal name for table but its a old database with too many data and relations , and I cant rename this table , is there any way to work with table ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Square Brackets  `[` and `]`  in the Column name,Table Name.

```
SELECT GroupID,GroupName FROM [Group]
```

other eg.

```
select * from [table]
select [primary] from [table]
```

P.S: it worked by adding [dbo] before [Group] , so it is now like :

```
 SELECT GroupID, GroupName FROM [dbo].[Group]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , but still same Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Group'.

Comment: Group is Your table name??

Comment: try like this sp_help 'Group' for table definition

Comment: I have added a [dbo].[Group] and is now working , thanks alot

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT GroupID, GroupName FROM `Group`
```

Now it knows `Group` is the name of a table rather than incorrectly placed language syntax

Comment: its not working this again it said : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Group'.

Answer (score 4):

It requires always quotes and it becomes case sensitive

So:

```
SELECT GroupID,GroupName FROM "Group"
```

if table name is group then:

```
SELECT GroupID,GroupName FROM "group"
```

be sure of the case of the name.

Although its not a good idea to use table names that need quoting and are reserved words.

If you can change the table name.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the database name before the table name or you can give the table an alias.

```
select t1.col1 
from db1.table1 t1
```

t1 - Being the table alias

db1 - Being the database name